# vk2828u7g5lf GPS module over SoftwareSerial

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, softwareserial, gps

So my goal was simple. Trying to get a GPS speed, and show it on a display (later use it to control a stepper motor). I am using the vk2828u7g5lf GPS module from Banggood, which after days of tinkering and trying several tutorials, I managed to make it work with ONLY the following code:

```
    boolean gpsStatus[] = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
unsigned long start;

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(3,2); // RX, TX

void setup()
{
  gpsSerial.begin(9600);
  // START OUR SERIAL DEBUG PORT
  Serial.begin(19200);
  //
  //Settings Array contains the following settings: [0]NavMode, [1]DataRate1, [2]DataRate2, [3]PortRateByte1, [4]PortRateByte2, [5]PortRateByte3,
  //[6]NMEA GLL Sentence, [7]NMEA GSA Sentence, [8]NMEA GSV Sentence, [9]NMEA RMC Sentence, [10]NMEA VTG Sentence
  //NavMode:
  //Pedestrian Mode    = 0x03
  //Automotive Mode    = 0x04
  //Sea Mode           = 0x05
  //Airborne < 1G Mode = 0x06
  //
  //DataRate:
  //1Hz     = 0xE8 0x03
  //2Hz     = 0xF4 0x01
  //3.33Hz  = 0x2C 0x01
  //4Hz     = 0xFA 0x00
  //
  //PortRate:
  //4800   = C0 12 00
  //9600   = 80 25 00
  //19200  = 00 4B 00  **SOFTWARESERIAL LIMIT FOR ARDUINO UNO R3!**
  //38400  = 00 96 00  **SOFTWARESERIAL LIMIT FOR ARDUINO MEGA 2560!**
  //57600  = 00 E1 00
  //115200 = 00 C2 01
  //230400 = 00 84 03
  //
  //NMEA Messages:
  //OFF = 0x00
  //ON  = 0x01
  //
  byte settingsArray[] = {0x03, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; //
  configureUblox(settingsArray);
}

void loop()
{
  while(1) {
    if(gpsSerial.available())
    {
    // THIS IS THE MAIN LOOP JUST READS IN FROM THE GPS SERIAL AND ECHOS OUT TO THE ARDUINO SERIAL.
    Serial.write(gpsSerial.read());
    }
  }
}


void configureUblox(byte *settingsArrayPointer) {
  byte gpsSetSuccess = 0;
  Serial.println("Configuring u-Blox GPS initial state...");

  //Generate the configuration string for Navigation Mode
  byte setNav[] = {0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x24, 0x24, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, *settingsArrayPointer, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x27, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x64, 0x00, 0x2C, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
  calcChecksum(&setNav[2], sizeof(setNav) - 4);

  //Generate the configuration string for Data Rate
  byte setDataRate[] = {0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x08, 0x06, 0x00, settingsArrayPointer[1], settingsArrayPointer[2], 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
  calcChecksum(&setDataRate[2], sizeof(setDataRate) - 4);

  //Generate the configuration string for Baud Rate
  byte setPortRate[] = {0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xD0, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, settingsArrayPointer[3], settingsArrayPointer[4], settingsArrayPointer[5], 0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
  calcChecksum(&setPortRate[2], sizeof(setPortRate) - 4);

  byte setGLL[] = {0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0xF0, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x2B};
  byte setGSA[] = {0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0xF0, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x32};
  byte setGSV[] = {0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0xF0, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x39};
  byte setRMC[] = {0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0xF0, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x04, 0x40};
  byte setVTG[] = {0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x01, 0x08, 0x00, 0xF0, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x46};

  delay(2500);

  while(gpsSetSuccess < 3)
  {
    Serial.print("Setting Navigation Mode... ");
    sendUBX(&setNav[0], sizeof(setNav));  //Send UBX Packet
    gpsSetSuccess += getUBX_ACK(&setNav[2]); //Passes Class ID and Message ID to the ACK Receive function
    if (gpsSetSuccess == 5) {
      gpsSetSuccess -= 4;
      setBaud(settingsArrayPointer[4]);
      delay(1500);
      byte lowerPortRate[] = {0xB5, 0x62, 0x06, 0x00, 0x14, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xD0, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA2, 0xB5};
      sendUBX(lowerPortRate, sizeof(lowerPortRate));
      gpsSerial.begin(9600);
      delay(2000);
    }
    if(gpsSetSuccess == 6) gpsSetSuccess -= 4;
    if (gpsSetSuccess == 10) gpsStatus[0] = true;
  }
  if (gpsSetSuccess == 3) Serial.println("Navigation mode configuration failed.");
  gpsSetSuccess = 0;
  while(gpsSetSuccess < 3) {
    Serial.print("Setting Data Update Rate... ");
    sendUBX(&setDataRate[0], sizeof(setDataRate));  //Send UBX Packet
    gpsSetSuccess += getUBX_ACK(&setDataRate[2]); //Passes Class ID and Message ID to the ACK Receive function
    if (gpsSetSuccess == 10) gpsStatus[1] = true;
    if (gpsSetSuccess == 5 | gpsSetSuccess == 6) gpsSetSuccess -= 4;
  }
  if (gpsSetSuccess == 3) Serial.println("Data update mode configuration failed.");
  gpsSetSuccess = 0;


  while(gpsSetSuccess < 3 && settingsArrayPointer[6] == 0x00) {
    Serial.print("Deactivating NMEA GLL Messages ");
    sendUBX(setGLL, sizeof(setGLL));
    gpsSetSuccess += getUBX_ACK(&setGLL[2]);
    if (gpsSetSuccess == 10) gpsStatus[2] = true;
    if (gpsSetSuccess == 5 | gpsSetSuccess == 6) gpsSetSuccess -= 4;
  }
  if (gpsSetSuccess == 3) Serial.println("NMEA GLL Message Deactivation Failed!");
  gpsSetSuccess = 0;

  while(gpsSetSuccess < 3 && settingsArrayPointer[7] == 0x00) {
    Serial.print("Deactivating NMEA GSA Messages ");
    sendUBX(setGSA, sizeof(setGSA));
    gpsSetSuccess += getUBX_ACK(&setGSA[2]);
    if (gpsSetSuccess == 10) gpsStatus[3] = true;
    if (gpsSetSuccess == 5 | gpsSetSuccess == 6) gpsSetSuccess -= 4;
  }
  if (gpsSetSuccess == 3) Serial.println("NMEA GSA Message Deactivation Failed!");
  gpsSetSuccess = 0;

  while(gpsSetSuccess < 3 && settingsArrayPointer[8] == 0x00) {
    Serial.print("Deactivating NMEA GSV Messages ");
    sendUBX(setGSV, sizeof(setGSV));
    gpsSetSuccess += getUBX_ACK(&setGSV[2]);
    if (gpsSetSuccess == 10) gpsStatus[4] = true;
    if (gpsSetSuccess == 5 | gpsSetSuccess == 6) gpsSetSuccess -= 4;
  }
  if (gpsSetSuccess == 3) Serial.println("NMEA GSV Message Deactivation Failed!");
  gpsSetSuccess = 0;

  while(gpsSetSuccess < 3 && settingsArrayPointer[9] == 0x00) {
    Serial.print("Deactivating NMEA RMC Messages ");
    sendUBX(setRMC, sizeof(setRMC));
    gpsSetSuccess += getUBX_ACK(&setRMC[2]);
    if (gpsSetSuccess == 10) gpsStatus[5] = true;
    if (gpsSetSuccess == 5 | gpsSetSuccess == 6) gpsSetSuccess -= 4;
  }
  if (gpsSetSuccess == 3) Serial.println("NMEA RMC Message Deactivation Failed!");
  gpsSetSuccess = 0;

  while(gpsSetSuccess < 3 && settingsArrayPointer[10] == 0x00) {
    Serial.print("Deactivating NMEA VTG Messages ");
    sendUBX(setVTG, sizeof(setVTG));
    gpsSetSuccess += getUBX_ACK(&setVTG[2]);
    if (gpsSetSuccess == 10) gpsStatus[6] = true;
    if (gpsSetSuccess == 5 | gpsSetSuccess == 6) gpsSetSuccess -= 4;
  }
  if (gpsSetSuccess == 3) Serial.println("NMEA VTG Message Deactivation Failed!");

  gpsSetSuccess = 0;
  if (settingsArrayPointer[4] != 0x25) {
    Serial.print("Setting Port Baud Rate... ");
    sendUBX(&setPortRate[0], sizeof(setPortRate));
    setBaud(settingsArrayPointer[4]);
    Serial.println("Success!");
    delay(500);
  }
}


void calcChecksum(byte *checksumPayload, byte payloadSize) {
  byte CK_A = 0, CK_B = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < payloadSize ;i++) {
    CK_A = CK_A + *checksumPayload;
    CK_B = CK_B + CK_A;
    checksumPayload++;
  }
  *checksumPayload = CK_A;
  checksumPayload++;
  *checksumPayload = CK_B;
}

void sendUBX(byte *UBXmsg, byte msgLength) {
  for(int i = 0; i < msgLength; i++) {
    gpsSerial.write(UBXmsg[i]);
    gpsSerial.flush();
  }
  gpsSerial.println();
  gpsSerial.flush();
}


byte getUBX_ACK(byte *msgID) {
  byte CK_A = 0, CK_B = 0;
  byte incoming_char;
  boolean headerReceived = false;
  unsigned long ackWait = millis();
  byte ackPacket[10] = {0xB5, 0x62, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
  int i = 0;
  while (1) {
    if (gpsSerial.available()) {
      incoming_char = gpsSerial.read();
      if (incoming_char == ackPacket[i]) {
        i++;
      }
      else if (i > 2) {
        ackPacket[i] = incoming_char;
        i++;
      }
    }
    if (i > 9) break;
    if ((millis() - ackWait) > 1500) {
      Serial.println("ACK Timeout");
      return 5;
    }
    if (i == 4 && ackPacket[3] == 0x00) {
      Serial.println("NAK Received");
      return 1;
    }
  }

  for (i = 2; i < 8 ;i++) {
  CK_A = CK_A + ackPacket[i];
  CK_B = CK_B + CK_A;
  }
  if (msgID[0] == ackPacket[6] && msgID[1] == ackPacket[7] && CK_A == ackPacket[8] && CK_B == ackPacket[9]) {
    Serial.println("Success!");
    Serial.print("ACK Received! ");
    printHex(ackPacket, sizeof(ackPacket));
    return 10;
        }
  else {
    Serial.print("ACK Checksum Failure: ");
    printHex(ackPacket, sizeof(ackPacket));
    delay(1000);
    return 1;
  }
}


void printHex(uint8_t *data, uint8_t length) // prints 8-bit data in hex
{
  char tmp[length*2+1];
  byte first ;
  int j=0;
  for (byte i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    first = (data[i] >> 4) | 48;
    if (first > 57) tmp[j] = first + (byte)7;
    else tmp[j] = first ;
    j++;

    first = (data[i] & 0x0F) | 48;
    if (first > 57) tmp[j] = first + (byte)7;
    else tmp[j] = first;
    j++;
  }
  tmp[length*2] = 0;
  for (byte i = 0, j = 0; i < sizeof(tmp); i++) {
    Serial.print(tmp[i]);
    if (j == 1) {
      Serial.print(" ");
      j = 0;
    }
    else j++;
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void setBaud(byte baudSetting) {
  if (baudSetting == 0x12) gpsSerial.begin(4800);
  if (baudSetting == 0x4B) gpsSerial.begin(19200);
  if (baudSetting == 0x96) gpsSerial.begin(38400);
  if (baudSetting == 0xE1) gpsSerial.begin(57600);
  if (baudSetting == 0xC2) gpsSerial.begin(115200);
  if (baudSetting == 0x84) gpsSerial.begin(230400);
}
```

However, this one doesn't have a simple getSpeed() function, so I've tried to move to a library like TinyGPS that does have said function. Everything compiles fine, but it seems I am not getting a GPS signal with this script, while I have an accurate reading with about 7 satellites of the first script. I've triple checked the baud rates, and they all match, so I am stuck here.

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#include <TinyGPS.h>

/* This sample code demonstrates the normal use of a TinyGPS object.
   It requires the use of SoftwareSerial, and assumes that you have a
   4800-baud serial GPS device hooked up on pins 4(rx) and 3(tx).
*/

TinyGPS gps;
SoftwareSerial ss(3,2);

static void smartdelay(unsigned long ms);
static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec);
static void print_int(unsigned long val, unsigned long invalid, int len);
static void print_date(TinyGPS &gps);
static void print_str(const char *str, int len);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(19200);

  Serial.print("Testing TinyGPS library v. "); Serial.println(TinyGPS::library_version());
  Serial.println("by Mikal Hart");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Sats HDOP Latitude  Longitude  Fix  Date       Time     Date Alt    Course Speed Card  Distance Course Card  Chars Sentences Checksum");
  Serial.println("          (deg)     (deg)      Age                      Age  (m)    --- from GPS ----  ---- to London  ----  RX    RX        Fail");
  Serial.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

  ss.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  float flat, flon;
  unsigned long age, date, time, chars = 0;
  unsigned short sentences = 0, failed = 0;
  static const double LONDON_LAT = 51.508131, LONDON_LON = -0.128002;

  print_int(gps.satellites(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_SATELLITES, 5);
  print_int(gps.hdop(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_HDOP, 5);
  gps.f_get_position(&flat, &flon, &age);
  print_float(flat, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 10, 6);
  print_float(flon, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 11, 6);
  print_int(age, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE, 5);
  print_date(gps);
  print_float(gps.f_altitude(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ALTITUDE, 7, 2);
  print_float(gps.f_course(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 7, 2);
  print_float(gps.f_speed_kmph(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_SPEED, 6, 2);
  print_str(gps.f_course() == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? "*** " : TinyGPS::cardinal(gps.f_course()), 6);
  print_int(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? 0xFFFFFFFF : (unsigned long)TinyGPS::distance_between(flat, flon, LONDON_LAT, LONDON_LON) / 1000, 0xFFFFFFFF, 9);
  print_float(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE : TinyGPS::course_to(flat, flon, LONDON_LAT, LONDON_LON), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 7, 2);
  print_str(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? "*** " : TinyGPS::cardinal(TinyGPS::course_to(flat, flon, LONDON_LAT, LONDON_LON)), 6);

  gps.stats(&chars, &sentences, &failed);
  print_int(chars, 0xFFFFFFFF, 6);
  print_int(sentences, 0xFFFFFFFF, 10);
  print_int(failed, 0xFFFFFFFF, 9);
  Serial.println();

  smartdelay(1000);
}

static void smartdelay(unsigned long ms)
{
  unsigned long start = millis();
  do 
  {
    while (ss.available())
      gps.encode(ss.read());
  } while (millis() - start < ms);
}

static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec)
{
  if (val == invalid)
  {
    while (len-- > 1)
      Serial.print('*');
    Serial.print(' ');
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(val, prec);
    int vi = abs((int)val);
    int flen = prec + (val < 0.0 ? 2 : 1); // . and -
    flen += vi >= 1000 ? 4 : vi >= 100 ? 3 : vi >= 10 ? 2 : 1;
    for (int i=flen; i<len; ++i)
      Serial.print(' ');
  }
  smartdelay(0);
}

static void print_int(unsigned long val, unsigned long invalid, int len)
{
  char sz[32];
  if (val == invalid)
    strcpy(sz, "*******");
  else
    sprintf(sz, "%ld", val);
  sz[len] = 0;
  for (int i=strlen(sz); i<len; ++i)
    sz[i] = ' ';
  if (len > 0) 
    sz[len-1] = ' ';
  Serial.print(sz);
  smartdelay(0);
}

static void print_date(TinyGPS &gps)
{
  int year;
  byte month, day, hour, minute, second, hundredths;
  unsigned long age;
  gps.crack_datetime(&year, &month, &day, &hour, &minute, &second, &hundredths, &age);
  if (age == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE)
    Serial.print("********** ******** ");
  else
  {
    char sz[32];
    sprintf(sz, "%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d ",
        month, day, year, hour, minute, second);
    Serial.print(sz);
  }
  print_int(age, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE, 5);
  smartdelay(0);
}

static void print_str(const char *str, int len)
{
  int slen = strlen(str);
  for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    Serial.print(i<slen ? str[i] : ' ');
  smartdelay(0);
}
```

The result of the last script looks like this:

```
Testing TinyGPS library v. 13
by Mikal Hart

Sats HDOP Latitude  Longitude  Fix  Date       Time     Date Alt    Course Speed Card  Distance Course Card  Chars Sentences Checksum
          (deg)     (deg)      Age                      Age  (m)    --- from GPS ----  ---- to London  ----  RX    RX        Fail
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**** **** ********* ********** **** ********** ******** **** ****** ****** ***** ***   *******  ****** ***   0     0         0        
**** **** ********* ********** **** ********** ******** **** ****** ****** ***** ***   *******  ****** ***   52    0         0        
**** **** ********* ********** **** ********** ******** **** ****** ****** ***** ***   *******  ****** ***   104   0         0        
**** **** ********* ********** **** ********** ******** **** ****** ****** ***** ***   *******  ****** ***   169   0         0        
**** **** ********* ********** **** ********** ******** **** ****** ****** ***** ***   *******  ****** ***   221   0         0
```

A list of libraries I've tried:
 - NeoGPS
 - NeoGPS (customized version of a forum)
 - TineGPS
 - AdafruitGPS

And some more random (video) tutorials online. If anyone could help me out on this one, I would be highly grateful! (and perhaps keep some hair on my head)

Comment: So it turned out it was a loose connection *facepalm*. Anyway, it still is far from usable. Now the data starts with a blank line, followed by actual gps data. Problem is that even without moving my module, the lat/long/and height (?) Is still moving around allot?

Answer (score 1):

The clue lies in this part of your first sketch:

```
//NMEA Messages:
//OFF = 0x00
//ON  = 0x01
//
byte settingsArray[] = {0x03, 0xFA, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; //
configureUblox(settingsArray);
```

The final entry in your configuration is `0x00` which is "turn off NEMA messages".

There's two things to note here:

1. You are not configuring the GPS receiver in your second code, and
2. All other GPS libraries of note parse NEMA messages, which your first code turns off.

You will need to replicate the configuration code from your first sketch in your second sketch, but *turning ON NEMA messages*.